# Spark datagrid alternatingItemColors

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I try to customize a spark datagrid with css file.
I have a problem with alternatingItemColors property because all lines are white.
The same code works fine with mx|DataGrid

```
   s|DataGrid
    {

        backgroundAlpha: 0.6;
        borderThickness: 1;
        borderColor: #0085Ac;
        /* Couleur de la zone de titre  */
        /*headerColors: #006699, #6ea4f8;*/
        headerColors : #6db8e0, #50a3ce;
        horizontalGridLines: false;
        verticalGridLines: true;
        verticalGridLineColor: #003366; 
        alternatingItemColors: #ffffff, #eeeeee;
        rollOverColor: #b3b7d9;
        textRollOverColor: #0c1e37;
        selection-color:#66B0C0;
        color :#0c1e37;

        headerStyleName: "mydataGridHeaderStyle";
    }
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the style name changed in the Spark DataGrid. It now has a style named [alternatingRowColors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#style%3aalternatingRowColors)